# Spring Boot App: Can't reach html file after .war package and Docker build

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, maven

I know is an old topic an was discussed many times before but I just can't get this done.

**ENVIRONMENT:**

I have a cicd pipeline setup. During the steps I create an html file with spring rest docs and ascii doch, pack my application to a .war file and finally build a Docker image. The index.html is placed in `/target/generated-docs`. With a mvn copy step I place it to /target/classes/static

**PROLEM:**

Like mentioned in the [docs](https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot), spring serves static content via different folders like `/static` or `/resources`

When I place the html file in my ide in `src/main/resources/static` , I can reach the html from the browser by just calling `localhost:8081`. So far so good. I want to acchieve the exact same behaviour, wehen I deploy my app with docker. ( Just use a compose for testing. This will be changed to kubernetes when this works).

So I researched in the documentation that the .war format should be the the right one as it is made for serving webapps. In my Jenkins file, I execute mvn clean package to build the war file. After some research I've read that static content should be placed on `src/main/webapp` in order to be served by a .war packaged application. So within my build pipeline I made shure that before the deployment, the html file is placed in src/main/webapp. However when I run the image within the compose container, I always geht a 404.

I also tried to leave it in the `/static` directory or to move it in `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF` but I just can't get it by hitting the url.

So the question is, where do I have to place the static content in order to serve it without a controller just by hitting the url or url/index.html

**UPDATE**

In my build stage I excute mvn package which creates my html file and moves it to `src/main/resources/static` directory. I validate this within my Jenkins file. In addition, I changed the packaing to jar. Finally I build my docker image.

But still I get a 404 when I hit the url either ip:port or ip:port/index.html. As info: The errorpage comes from the webserver, so my port mapping in docker is correct

Comment: Don't change to war, just use jar.

Comment: An explanation would be nice

Comment: a war is for deployment in a servlet container, which you don't do. Just use a jar which includes tomcat etc.

Comment: Why are things being moved in the first place? Your  HTML file should already be in that location. Looks like you are messing things up in your build by trying to be smarter then what the plugin already does.

Comment: My fault. I use spring rest docs. The result html is generated in /asciidoc. So I thought I have to move the html to the /static folder in order to be served?

Comment: You might want to clarify that in your question. Although adding an additional static resource folder to your configuration would probably save you from moving things around in the first place. (or configure restdocs to generate it elsewhere).

Comment: I'll update the question. The problem is that spring rest docs creates the docs in '${project.build.directory}/generated-docs' so I have to move it by copy to e.g. the /static folder right?